# Modify and Plot overlay using JSON Fabric js

Tags: json, fabricjs, openseadragon, jsonparser

I have generated a JSON file with x, y coordinates to draw polylines using Fabric JS. However, my current problem is the coordinate system that I use is image pixels while the canvas I am drawing is openseadragon (OSD). Therefore, I will need to change the coordinates system from image pixels to viewport coordinate.

I know there is a function in openseadragon `imageToViewportCoordinates` that may do the conversion. However, the problem is how can I parse out the x , y coordinates, convert them and draw the polylines on fabric js canvas?

The JSON file is as below:

```
{"version":"2.0.0-beta7","objects":[
    {"type":"polyline","fill":"rgba(250,0,0,0.8)","points":[
            {"x":61146,"y":155098}
        ]},
    {"type":"polyline","fill":"rgba(250,0,0,0.8)","points":[
            {"x":61658,"y":154330}
        ]},
    {"type":"polyline","fill":"rgba(250,0,0,0.8)","points":[
            {"x":66778,"y":152538}
        ]},
    {"type":"polyline","fill":"rgba(250,0,0,0.8)","points":[
            {"x":67034,"y":152026}
        ]},
    {"type":"polyline","fill":"rgba(250,0,0,0.8)","points":[
            {"x":60634,"y":151002},
            {"x":60378,"y":151258},
            {"x":60122,"y":151258},
            {"x":59866,"y":151258},
            {"x":59610,"y":151258},
            {"x":59354,"y":151514},
            {"x":59098,"y":151514},
            {"x":58842,"y":151514},
            {"x":58586,"y":151770},
            {"x":58330,"y":151770},
            {"x":58074,"y":152026},
            {"x":57818,"y":152282},
            {"x":57562,"y":152282},
            {"x":57306,"y":152282},
            {"x":57306,"y":152538},
            {"x":57050,"y":152794},
            {"x":56794,"y":152794},
            {"x":56538,"y":153050},
            {"x":56538,"y":153306},
            {"x":56794,"y":153306},
            {"x":57050,"y":153306},
            {"x":57306,"y":153050},
            {"x":57562,"y":152794},
            {"x":57818,"y":152794},
            {"x":58074,"y":153050},
            {"x":58330,"y":153306},
            {"x":58586,"y":153562},
            {"x":58842,"y":153562},
            {"x":59098,"y":153562},
            {"x":59354,"y":153306},
            {"x":59610,"y":153562},
            {"x":59866,"y":153818},
            {"x":60122,"y":154074},
            {"x":60378,"y":154074},
            {"x":60634,"y":154074},
            {"x":60890,"y":153818},
            {"x":61146,"y":153818},
            {"x":61402,"y":153818},
            {"x":61146,"y":153562},
            {"x":61402,"y":153306},
            {"x":61658,"y":153050},
            {"x":61914,"y":153306},
            {"x":62170,"y":153562},
            {"x":62170,"y":153818},
            {"x":62426,"y":153818},
            {"x":62682,"y":153818},
            {"x":62938,"y":154074},
            {"x":63194,"y":154074},
            {"x":63450,"y":154330},
            {"x":63194,"y":154586},
            {"x":62938,"y":154586},
            {"x":62682,"y":154586},
            {"x":62682,"y":154842},
            {"x":62426,"y":155098},
            {"x":62170,"y":155098},
            {"x":61914,"y":155354},
            {"x":61914,"y":155610},
            {"x":62170,"y":155610},
            {"x":62426,"y":155610},
            {"x":62682,"y":155866},
            {"x":62682,"y":156122},
            {"x":62426,"y":156378},
            {"x":62682,"y":156634},
            {"x":62426,"y":156890},
            {"x":62170,"y":156890},
            {"x":61914,"y":157146},
            {"x":61658,"y":156890},
            {"x":61402,"y":156890},
            {"x":61146,"y":156634},
            {"x":61402,"y":156378},
            {"x":61146,"y":156634},
            {"x":61146,"y":156890},
            {"x":61146,"y":157146},
            {"x":61402,"y":156890},
            {"x":61658,"y":157146},
            {"x":61658,"y":157402},
            {"x":61402,"y":157658},
            {"x":61146,"y":157914},
            {"x":61146,"y":158170},
            {"x":60890,"y":158426},
            {"x":60634,"y":158682},
            {"x":60634,"y":158938},
            {"x":60890,"y":159194},
            {"x":60890,"y":159450},
            {"x":60890,"y":159706},
            {"x":60890,"y":159962},
            {"x":60890,"y":160218},
            {"x":60890,"y":159962},
            {"x":60890,"y":159706},
            {"x":61146,"y":159450},
            {"x":61402,"y":159194},
            {"x":61658,"y":158938},
            {"x":61914,"y":158682},
            {"x":62170,"y":158682},
            {"x":62426,"y":158426},
            {"x":62682,"y":158682},
            {"x":62682,"y":158426},
            {"x":62938,"y":158170},
            {"x":63194,"y":158170},
            {"x":63194,"y":157914},
            {"x":63450,"y":157658},
            {"x":63706,"y":157658},
            {"x":63962,"y":157402},
            {"x":64218,"y":157146},
            {"x":64474,"y":157146},
            {"x":64730,"y":156890},
            {"x":64986,"y":156634},
            {"x":65242,"y":156634},
            {"x":64986,"y":156378},
            {"x":65242,"y":156122},
            {"x":65242,"y":155866},
            {"x":65498,"y":155610},
            {"x":65498,"y":155354},
            {"x":65498,"y":155098},
            {"x":65754,"y":154842},
            {"x":65498,"y":154586},
            {"x":65498,"y":154330},
            {"x":65498,"y":154074},
            {"x":65242,"y":153818},
            {"x":65242,"y":153562},
            {"x":65242,"y":153306},
            {"x":64986,"y":153050},
            {"x":64986,"y":152794},
            {"x":64730,"y":152538},
            {"x":64474,"y":152282},
            {"x":64218,"y":152026},
            {"x":63962,"y":151770},
            {"x":63706,"y":151514},
            {"x":63706,"y":151258},
            {"x":63450,"y":151258},
            {"x":63194,"y":151258},
            {"x":62938,"y":151002},
            {"x":62682,"y":151002},
            {"x":62426,"y":151258},
            {"x":62170,"y":151514},
            {"x":61914,"y":151258},
            {"x":61658,"y":151258},
            {"x":61402,"y":151002},
            {"x":61146,"y":151002},
            {"x":60890,"y":151002}
        ]}]}
```

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you tell more about OSD image size? Also are you using fabricjs-overlay library? It looks like you are trying to draw polylines with very big coordinates like x: 60890 px and y: 151002 px. Also, first 4 polylines will not be visible as long as they don't have a 2 points.

Comment: Size of this particular image is 97792(W) x 221184(H). Right, I am using fabricjs-overlay library so that I can use JSON format to represent my overlay coordinates.

Comment: Can you update you question with a code how are you doing actual drawing of the shapes?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your viewport coordinates to match the coordinates you have in your JSON. For instance if you want the coordinates to stretch from 0 to 61,000, you could do this:

```
var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
  ...
  tileSources: {
    tileSource: url,
    width: 61000
  }
});
```